# How to pass the some of values from the textbox grid to another page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

[image: form layout with textboxes for amounts]

I need to make a cart system form like this in that section I will add the amount and then I select the checkbox and will checkout after that values will go to the next page with sum:

[image: form layout with total price]

I have made this code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="Basket" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    GridLines="None" EnableViewState="False" ShowFooter="True" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnRowCreated="Basket_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="RemovedProducts" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Donation" SortExpression="ProductName">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="ProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <strong>
            Total Price:
          </strong>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="UnitPrice">
        <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Eval("UnitPrice")%>   aed
       </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <strong>
            <asp:Literal ID="TotalPrice" runat="server" /> AED
          </strong>
        </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:Button ID="RemoveDonation" runat="server" 
    Text="Remove From Basket"     OnClick="RemoveProduct_Click" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <asp:Button ID="ConfirmPurchase" runat="server" Text="Confirm Donation" />
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BasketData" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the code:

```
protected void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var selectedProducts = Products.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
        .Where(row => ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("SelectedProducts")).Checked)
        .Select(row => Products.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).ToList();
      if (Session["Cart"] == null)
      {
        Session["Cart"] = selectedProducts;
      }
      else
      {
        var cart = (List<string>)Session["Cart"];
        foreach (var product in selectedProducts)
          cart.Add(product);
        Session["Cart"] = cart;
      }
      foreach (GridViewRow row in Products.Rows)
      {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("SelectedProducts");
        if (cb.Checked)
          cb.Checked = false;

      }
    }

    protected void Checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx");
    }
```

When go to the next page how will I retrieve the total amount entered in the textbox and display it?

Comment: Your mark up is different from design. Are you using textboxes to get amount?

Comment: you can maintain the values between pages using session and other state management techniques.

Comment: yes i will enter the amount in the textbox in gridview and will store all the values in session and when i click the checkout button i will go to next page there what i want is the total of the values added in textbox

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC (tag removed)

Comment: @SainPradeep i am new to asp.net can you please tel me how to retrieve the amount from the session["cart"] and make the sum

Comment: you will find many example on the google for this. Please refer this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-shopping-cart-in-aspnet--net-1663

Comment: use any state management technique depending on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Page_Load event of your next page you can create a label to display the total price, then you just need to assign the session value to label.text

```
Label TotalPrice = default(Label);
TotalPrice.text = Session["Cart"].ToString
```

I am use to vb.net so if my C# syntax is off I apologize